# Is Higgs cosmology a largely ignored theory, and if it is, why?

Tags: cosmology, higgs, dark-matter, dark-energy

(I am not a cosmologist and instead currently working on a master thesis about Feynman integrals, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious. This question is merely out of interest.)

I was wondering whether there are people working on Higgs cosmology and if they are not, then why are they not? Is there some clear prediction which contradicts observations?
I have seen a lot of theories mentioned with 'dark matter coupled to Higgs', but rarely that Higgs itself could be dark matter.

For clarity, with 'Higgs cosmology' I'm referring to the following idea I have encountered a few times in conversation but never seen in my Cosmology course or in media like Wikipedia:

- The Higgs particle has a vacuum expectation (after symmetry breaking etc.) but also has interactions with mass. Therefore, the actual value of the Higgs field in the neighbourhood of mass may differ significantly from the vacuum expectation.
- This means that near large masses (e.g. a star) one would expect the Higgs field to have a significantly different expectation depending on the distance from the star, becoming the vacuum expectation in the large-distance limit.
- This means that stars could have an effective 'halo' from the Higgs field. If this halo is short-range one would not expect any cosmological relevance, but if it is sufficiently long-ranged it will have effect as follows.
- Two nearby stars will both have a halo, so now the interactions are not only star -- star (gravity) but also halo -- star, star -- halo and halo -- halo. The halo -- star attraction might contribute to dark matter, while the halo -- halo interaction is even more unclear and might provide a very long-range force hence either contributing or working against dark energy.

(One remark: If the halo is indeed sufficiently long-ranged then the results from CERN have to be taken a bit more nuanced, for the setup at CERN can make a matter-vacuum and make it dark, but can not avoid being inside the Higgs-halo of all the matter nearby.)

Again, I am not a cosmologist so I wouldn't notice gaping holes in the theory. Could someone please explain why this theory is not popular?

Comment: "the following idea I have encountered a few times in conversation" Do these people know how to calculate the magnitude of their proposed effect?

Comment: @mitchellPorter No, this was in a conversation with string theorists and/or particle theorists, none of us have any clear ties with cosmology.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. Calculating a supposed shift in the higgs VEV, due to interactions with mass, is not a problem in cosmology, it's a problem in quantum field theory... I doubt very much that this is a real thing. The "Higgs force" for anything other than the top quark should be negligible, and even there is negligible at anything other than very short distances. Also, if the higgs VEV was different near celestial bodies, the masses e.g. of electrons should be different and it would show in the spectroscopic properties of atoms.

Comment: There is the question of why we apparently don't feel the higgs VEV as an overwhelming source of gravity, but that is just one component of the cosmological constant problem and whether vacuum energy gravitates.

Comment: @mitchellPorter Okay, so the point is that we already know that the "Higgs force" would be extremely short-distance? In that case, is any Dark Matter theory where dark matter relies on interactions with the Higgs field doomed because those theories can not build a substantional halo?

Comment: I don't know what it means for dark matter to "rely on" interactions with the Higgs field. Dark matter particles need to have mass. If their mass came from Higgs interactions, then I suppose that would be a dependency, but it wouldn't require the Higgs vev to vary. And mass of dark matter can have other sources, indeed doesn't come from Higgs in most theories.

Comment: If you're referring to this idea that "dark matter" is actually Higgs field with higher vev, or is an effect otherwise originating with the Higgs field, I need to hear a more coherent explanation of how it works. If you could ask one of your informants for a more precise description, that would help.

Comment: @mitchellporter I meant with 'rely on' that you sometimes hear about DM theories which can not be explained purely with gravity and hence they include a weak interaction or similar (my knowledge about this is very limited). I think that from your comments I can conclude that this 'similar' is never Higgs, because using Higgs simply doesn't solve a lot of problems?

Comment: @mitchelporter As for the origin of this whole idea, it seems to be from proposed TOEs (or larger GUTs) which usually only have Yang-Mills-like fields, Higgs-like fields and fermions hence if such a TOE is to explain everything then DM and DE must be caused by a Higgs-like field (under assumptions about fermions). This appears to be the only motivation for Higgs-like dark matter.
(An example of such a TOE is the Weyl-Einstein-Yang-Mills model by Dengiz,  arXiv:1609.02475.)

Comment: "DM theories which can not be explained purely with gravity and hence they include a weak interaction or similar" Hmm. The idea of weaklike interaction in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particles paradigm has to do with production of the dark matter particles in early universe. But as dark matter only their mass, and hence only their gravitational effect, is relevant...

Comment: As for "Higgs-like", if we are no longer talking specifically about standard model Higgs, but any Higgs-like fields, then the range of models must become very broad. The idea of getting the dark matter halo from the gradient of a vev sounds a little strange, though perhaps not impossible. But if it's not the standard model Higgs, then it wouldn't be associated with the baryonic matter in celestial bodies, which I thought was part of the scenario.

Comment: I'll also mention that there are theories of gravity in which along with a spin-2 graviton, there is a spin-0 component to the gravitational field as well. So a new scalar field that couples to matter. Maybe that is what these people are talking about? But then why would this be called "Higgs cosmology"? If the idea is that this "scalar graviton" actually *is* the standard model Higgs, it doesn't make sense because SM Higgs has to have electroweak charge.

Comment: There actually are proposals for a cosmological role for the SM Higgs field, most notably "Higgs inflation", and one could also mention, e.g., "Higgsogenesis" of dark matter. But I can't think of anything which sounds like what you describe.

Comment: @mitchellporter Thank you very much. I didn't know that Higgs-like fields are significantly different from SM Higgs, I think that is the key I was missing, although like you remark it has to couple strongly to matter in some sense for the theory to even predict haloes, and probably a Higgs-like field that couples strongly must be the Higgs field itself.

Comment: Going from Higgs to Higgs-like probably gives so much probabilities that there are no clear boundaries of a Higgs-like-cosmology theory, meaning it will be very hard to say something about it without further assumption? If that is the case, that answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalar field cosmology is widely studied (under the name scalar tensor theories) to answer several questions of cosmology. Higgs field is particularly used to drive the expansion of spacetime in the early epochs (Higgs Inflation). It has been also used to study the dark sector.

Higgs particle itself cannot be a dark matter candidate for a simple reason as it decays very quickly. The Dark matter on the other hand should be a stable particle and should not interact through electromagnetism (both conditions wont apply to higgs particle themselves). We can however introduce new force carriers and try to explain dark matter.

Higgs can only act as a gravitational force (like dark matter particles) in the very early epochs of the universe where, $H$ the Hubble rate is much larger than 246 GeV.